# python gspread - How to get a spreadsheet URL path in after i create it?

Tags: python, url, google-sheets, google-drive-api, gspread

I'm trying to create a new spreadsheet using the `gspread` python package, then get its URL path (inside the google drive) and send it to other people so they could go in as well.

I tried to find an answer [here](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/02/an-easy-way-to-read-and-write-to-a-google-spreadsheet-in-python.html) and [here](https://github.com/burnash/gspread), with no luck.

I created a brand new Spreadsheet:

`import gspread
from gspread_dataframe import get_as_dataframe, set_with_dataframe 
gc = gspread_connect()
spreadsheet = gc.create('TESTING SHEET')`

Then i Shared it with my account:

`spreadsheet.share('my_user@my_company.com', perm_type='user', role='writer')`

Then i wrote some random stuff into it:

`worksheet = gc.open('TESTING SHEET').sheet1
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records([{'a': i, 'b': i * 2} for i in range(100)])
set_with_dataframe(worksheet, df)`

Now when i go to my google drive i can find this sheet by looking for its name ("TESTING SHEET")

But i didn't figure how do i get the URL path in my python code, so i could pass it right away to other people.

Tnx!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can generate the URL by using [`Spreadsheet.id`](https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#gspread.models.Spreadsheet.id). Here's an example that uses `spreadsheet` variable from your code:

```
spreadsheet_url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/%s" % spreadsheet.id
```

Comment: I've also tried these approaches:
SPREADSHEET_ID = '1mhPl2p2TV6lHn-9xxxxxxhXdnThSBOyMbI'
spreadsheet_url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/{}".format(SPREADSHEET_ID)
print(spreadsheet_url)
gc.open(SPREADSHEET_ID)
# gc.open_by_url(spreadsheet_url)
# gc.open(spreadsheet_url)
# gc.open_by_key(SPREADSHEET_ID)